# Error inflating class <unknown> with own Class

Tags: java, android, xml

What can be cause of error inflating class `<unknown>`? There are two `.xml` files. First `.xml` works, second one kills the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3 товара на сумму"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/summ"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ruble"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/description" />
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.PriceText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/finish"
        android:text="ОФОРМИТЬ"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/main"
        android:background="@color/lavka_main_red" />    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Вторая

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--android:background="@color/main"-->    

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/image" />
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image" />

    <com.widget.lavkaviews.PriceText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/price"/>

    <!--<com.widget.lavkaviews.PriceText-->
        <!--android:layout_width="80dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="20dp"-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/price"-->
        <!--android:textColor="#262626"-->
        <!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />-->

    <com.widget.lavkaviews.Dropdown
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/portion"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/incrementor" />
    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/price"-->

    <com.widget.lavkaviews.Incrementor
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/incrementor"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/portion" />
    <com.widget.core.view.ProductNDIndicator
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nd"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error is on inflating `PriceText` class. Error produces at the emulator (genymotion) and physical device in second `.xml` file. Here is stacktrace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at com.lavkalavka.pages.cart.CartFragment$CartAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(CartFragment.java:241)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5223)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4449)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4359)
        at com.widget.core.layoutmanagers.LinearLayoutManager.measureChild(LinearLayoutManager.java:235)
        at com.widget.core.layoutmanagers.LinearLayoutManager.onMeasure(LinearLayoutManager.java:125)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2563)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1196)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:318)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1196)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:318)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.market.lavkalavka"

    >

<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="23" />
    <permission android:name="com.market.lavkalavka.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- GCM permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.market.lavkalavka.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- YandexMaps-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>    

    <application
        android:name="com.lavkalavka.App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:icon="@drawable/logobadge"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >    

        <!-- Yandex метрика-->
        <service
            android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":Metrica">

            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="com.yandex.metrica.IMetricaService"/>
                <data android:scheme="metrica"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="metrica:api:level" android:value="32"/>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">

            <!-- INSTALL_REFERRER необходим для трэкинга кампаний -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.lavkalavka.yametrika.InstallReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Yandex метрика-->    

        <!-- Facebook API-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
        "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <!-- Facebook API-->

        <!-- VKontakte API-->
        <meta-data android:name="com.vk.sdk.AppId" android:value="4695634" />
        <!--<activity android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKOpenAuthActivity" />-->
        <activity android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity"
            android:label="ServiceActivity" android:theme="@style/VK.Transparent" />
        <!-- VKontakte API-->

        <!-- GCM Service-->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.market.lavkalavka" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.lavkalavka.gcm.UpdateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH" />
                <data android:path="com.market.lavkalavka"
                    android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.lavkalavka.gcm.GCMIntentService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!-- GCM Service-->


        <activity android:name="com.lavkalavka.pages.map.YandexMapActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.lavkalavka.pages.root.DrawerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.lavkalavka.pages.root.OopsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:name="com.lavkalavka.pages.root.ShieldActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>    
    </application>
</manifest>
```

PriceText xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#2b2b2b"
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:text="133"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/ruble"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/price"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is `com.widget.lavkaviews` package is in your application ?

Comment: yes, it package for UI elements

Comment: What is your code at line number #23?

Comment: Line 23 is <com.widget.lavkaviews.PriceText, Error in project on inflating this xml.

Comment: What is PriceText actually?

Comment: Check that both XML has defined in manifest under <activity>

Comment: it is RelativeLayout with TextView and ImageView aligned centervertical of parent (image - ruble symbol). Maded for smooth representation of those views

Comment: Can you post that **PriceText** file?

Comment: Srinivasan, hmmm, must I define all layouts in manifest, even items and fragments layouts?

Comment: Nigam Patro, sure, one minute

Comment: @iamthevoid text is a custom TextView class right?

Comment: Yep, with own typeface and few own methods

Comment: @iamthevoid replace com.widget.lavkaviews.PriceText with com.market.lavkalavka.PriceText

Comment: Nigam Patro, try it, but it not worked. My package name is not root of the src files. I think using the full path in src is more correct

Answer (score 1):

Whats your Logcat Throws

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file
>   line #23: Error inflating class at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)

1. Add your Custom Textview class **`com.market.lavkalavka.PriceText`** (In XML)

Comment: Usually i use the full path to class, not the package name

Comment: It happens, that the package name is not root of the file hierarchy (it is my firs project :-[)

Comment: I cannot extend PriceText from TextView, because i must place ImageView with ruble symbol near TextView.

Comment: You can use `TextView` property ' android:drawableRight` to add your ruble symbol image to a TextView. So you could use that instead of a RelativeLayout.

Comment: `public class PriceText extends TextView {`

Comment: Drawable is rendered SVG image, i can place it only programmaticaly. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, the method is named quite strangely `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`. You have to provide drawables for all 4 sides, just provide null for the ones you do not need.

Comment: :( I must support 16 api, but this method is for 17 and higher api only.

Comment: @iamthevoid Then you use 17 for your feature

Comment: Mayybe is there the way to fix it on api 16?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you custom class is not extending from `View`.

```
public class PieChart extends View {

    public PieChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    //Do anything specific to your view. 

}
```

**Check out [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) Article on custom Views**

Comment: it extending from RelativeLayout, as you can see in my question